# Hidden layer youtube video, on visible not loading IE7

Tags: jquery, html, css, xhtml, html-helper

I have a html page. Which has few tabs (jquery). One of the hidden tab has youtube video.
On the tab gets visible, the youtube video loads in IE8 and FF 3.6.

But on IE7 it tries to load, but disappears.

Please help me out to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, there are some nasty bugs to do with plugins and `visibility: hidden`/`display: none`.

Instead of hiding the tab in either of those ways, try absolute-positioning it with a position like `left: -1024px` to move it way off-screen. Then on show, remove the left-positioning to drop it back where it's supposed to be.

Or you can create the Flash object dynamically when the tab is shown if you prefer.